# Rails adding artifacts to schema.rb after migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 7:

Migration:

```
class AddSavedSearchAPIKeyIndex < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    execute <<~SQL
      ALTER TABLE saved_searches
      ADD INDEX ecomm_analyze_api_key ((
        CAST(configuration->>"$.ecomm_analyze_api_key" as CHAR(255)) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
      )) USING BTREE;
    SQL
  end
end
```

My schema ends up looking like this:

```
t.index "(cast(json_unquote(json_extract(`configuration`,_utf8mb4\\'$.ecomm_analyze_api_key\\')) as char(255) charset utf8mb4) collate utf8mb4_bin)", name: "ecomm_analyze_api_key"
```

I can't load this schema.rb without getting an error when I use:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare
```

Error message

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
```

I am able to fix this by manually editing the `schema.rb` but this will just break again on the next migration.

Comment: Have you considered switching from `schema.rb` to `structure.sql`?

Comment: I'd love to find a solution that does not require a swap to `structure.sql`. Our team briefly used `structure.sql`, but we switched back to `schema.rb` for some legitimate reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby schema dumper only actually understands a limited subset of SQL that can be created by the migrations DSL and is only actually useful until your app reaches the degree of complexity where you want to use database specific features.

Anything else that the Ruby schema dumper doesn't properly understand like this index will either be mangled or just lost in translation when it tries to parse the resulting SQL from dumping the database schema.

The solution is to use SQL schema dumps instead:

```ruby
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Add this line:
    config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
  end
end
```

This will dump the file `structure.sql` which should serve as the source of truth for the database schema. Check this file into version control and delete `schema.rb` to avoid confusion.

See:

- [Rails Guides : Schema Dumping and You](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#schema-dumping-and-you)
- [Pros and Cons of Using structure.sql in Your Ruby on Rails Application](https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html)